# Where Has OktaClient Class Gone?

Tags: .net, okta

I'm trying to get some basic Okta functionality working (from my non-Web .NET app, checking if the current user is logged in to Okta). In my code I have the following Nuget packages installed but none of them seem to have the `OktaClient` class:

- Okta.Sdk (7.0.2)
- Okta.Auth.Sdk (2.0.5)
- Okta.Sdk.Abstractions (4.0.6)

In addition, I cannot find `SessionsClient` or `UsersClient`. According to [this documentation](https://developer.okta.com/okta-sdk-dotnet/latest/api/Okta.Sdk.OktaClient.html), the `OktaClient` class should be in the `Okta.Sdk` package.

Comment: The documentation you've linked to is from version 3.2.1, from April 2020 as far as I can tell. I suggest you read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-started) section of GitHub instead.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#oktaclient-vs-api-clients

Comment: I updated the link to the docs to the "latest"....supposedly...Maybe Okta has not kept up their docs.